# Divide program in 3 classes (Inheritance)

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to java. I want to divide my code into 3 classes. First class to contain my GUI, second to compute the algorithm and third class to write results in my file. I have the code working but i can't get to divide it in 3 separate classes, basically in my method Computer() i have all the 3 steps and i want to divide that method in 2 separate classes, therefor ill have GUI class, algorithm class and writer to file class. i will upload 3 images with my attempts, thank you.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PrimeNumbers {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;


    public static void main(String[] args) {



        PrimeNumbers window = new PrimeNumbers();
        window.frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    public PrimeNumbers() {
        initialize();
    }


    public  List<Integer> Calculate() throws IOException {
        String getTxt = textField.getText();
        Integer x = Integer.parseInt(getTxt);
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        boolean [] isComposite = new boolean [x + 1];
        isComposite[1] = true;


        for (int i = 2; i <= x; i++) {
            if (!isComposite[i]) {

                list.add(i);
                int multiple = 2;
                while (i * multiple <= x) {
                    isComposite [i * multiple] = true;
                    multiple++;
                }
            }
        }
        File file = new File("C:/Users/TudorV/Desktop/File.csv");


        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(String.valueOf(list));
        bw.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, list);
        return list;
    }



    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        textField = new JTextField();
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnGetPrimeNumbers = new JButton("Get prime numbers");
        btnGetPrimeNumbers.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    Calculate();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnGetPrimeNumbers, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

}
```

Comment: That’s a good idea. :-) What, more precisely, is stopping you?

Comment: Please show us your attempts and/or a simplified description of how you'd think it could work. Besides that, please have a look a the Java code conventions which discourage method names that start with an uppercase character (e.g. `List<Integer> Calculate()`).

Comment: I don't know what class should extend the other, how to set the parameter x that will be set in GUI class to work in algorithm class, like the 3 img i ve uploaded

Comment: if your code works, forget SO, I suggest you post it at: http://codereview.stackexchange.com they will be more gentle, not like @OleV.V. (for example) and will suggest you best options to your needs

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/o65bU.png

[2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zSHIr.png

  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/O20fN.png   Here are my attempts

Comment: @TudorVelcescu: Why do you want any of these classes to extend each other. This absolutely makes no sense in this case.

Comment: @TudorVelcescu - Saw the attempts. Hopefully there are no compilation errors and it looks good. What is the problem now?

Comment: @TudorVelcescu: By the way, instead of adding images to a comment, just edit your question.

Comment: I just want to separate the code in 3 classes, and by example, i compute the result list in  Computer class, and i want to add the parameter list to  Writter class and so on

Comment: I suggest you migrate your question to codereview as @JordiCastilla said :)

Comment: As far as i know if i make 3 classes to run a program i need to extend one another but I'm not sure that's why i'm asking

Comment: @TudorVelcescu: No, that's a misconception. Inheritance is not required here and also makes no sense.

Comment: How can i save the parameters from 1 class to use in the other if i don t use inheritance , can you give me a small example based on my code ? Like how can i use the list parameter in computer() class to work in Writter() class?

Comment: What version of Java are you using? I'm seeing several opportunities for using newer Java features.

Comment: @4castle I'm using java 8

Answer (score 0):

In Java, to access other class methods you have to create instances of those classes using the new operator. In your case, since `PrimeNumbers` is the class having the main method, you will do something like this inside the class

```
Computer computer = new Computer();
List<Integer> list = computer.Calculate(5);
```

Similarly to write a file

```
Writer writer = new Writer();
writer.write(list);
```

All this has to be done at the appropriate places where you want to perform those functions.

First three links for learning more about java - courtesy Google

[Oracle - Learning Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/)

[Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/)

[Java Beginners Tutorial](http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/core-java/)

Answer (score 0):

Your classes don't need to extend anything in order to be useful, but when using swing, it's often useful to extend `JFrame` so that you don't need to prefix everything with a `JFrame` object. One option is to make utlity classes so that your code is more reusable among different classes.

You can also use some features like [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) (Java 7) or [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) (Java 8).

**PrimeNumbers.java**

```
public class PrimeNumbers extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PrimeNumbers();
    }

    public PrimeNumbers() {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
        JButton btnGetPrimeNumbers = new JButton("Get prime numbers");
        btnGetPrimeNumbers.addActionListener(arg -> {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
            List<Integer> primes = PrimesUtil.getPrimesLessThan(num);
            FilesUtil.writeToFile(primes.toString());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, primes);
        });

        getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(btnGetPrimeNumbers, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**PrimesUtil.java**

```
public class PrimesUtil {
    public static List<Integer> getPrimesLessThan(int x) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean[] isComposite = new boolean[x + 1];
        isComposite[1] = true;
        for (int i = 2; i <= x; i++) {
            if (!isComposite[i]) {
                list.add(i);
                int multiple = 2;
                while (i * multiple <= x) {
                    isComposite[i * multiple] = true;
                    multiple++;
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

**FilesUtil.java**

```
public class FilesUtil {
    public static void writeToFile(String str) {
        File file = new File("C:/Users/TudorV/Desktop/File.csv");
        try (Writer w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
            w.write(str);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the awesome explanation!